# Change the row height dynamically using react-data-grid

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, grid, height, react-data-grid

[image]

I am using react-data-grid library.

2nd column's first row content is
'**It is a long text, though it is not displaying the whole content. as a solution, I want to change the row height dynamically**'

So how can I change the row height dynamically?
**rowHeight** won't work in my case

likewise, permission group column also has many labels like **pg3, pg4**. there also only one label is appearing.

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue in which I need to expand the cell height dynamically because of the larger content.

Comment: Did anyone ever figure out how to do this? I know that the v7 Canary version of RDG supports dynamic row heights, but the official example leaves something to be desired.